# How to pull out the string via regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
>>> x
'Content Type: TV Mini-Series\n\n\n                    &nbsp;-&nbsp;705 min&nbsp;-&nbsp;Action|Drama|History |'
```

I want to pull out the value "Mini-Series", without anything before or after it. This is what I have so far:

```
>>> re.match(r'.+TV Mini-Series', x).group(0)
'Content Type: TV Mini-Series'
```

How would I only get the "TV Mini-Series" text?

Comment: `re.match(r'.+TV Mini-Series', x).group(0).split(': ')[1]`?

Comment: Just use a normal HTTP parser and forget about buggy solutions, will you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search based on `Mini-Series` and want `'TV Mini-Series` you can put a possible leading with a space in your pattern .so as `TV` is upper case letters `[A-Z]*` could match any combine of uppercase letters before `Mini-Series`!

```
>>> re.search(r'[A-Z]* Mini-Series',x).group(0)
'TV Mini-Series'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.search` would be better suited to this:

```
>>> re.search(r'TV Mini-Series', x).group(0)
'TV Mini-Series'
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex seems like an overkill when you can simply use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> x = 'Content Type: TV Mini-Series\n\n\n                    &nbsp;-&nbsp;705 min&nbsp;-&nbsp;Action|Drama|History |'
>>> x.split('\n', 1)[0].split(maxsplit=2)[2]
'TV Mini-Series'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

> re.match(r'.+ (TV Mini-Series)', x).group(1)
>   => 'TV Mini-Series'

Note: you want to use group(1) because group(0) is defined to capture the whole string